# How to partition harddisk for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I want to partition my hard disk, but I don't have any other software running(like dual booted).

And I do not know how to do it.
Can you send the instructions?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to prepare in advance a partition for installing Ubuntu 18.04 as a single boot. The Ubuntu installer is able to create the partition for installing Ubuntu in either of two ways: automatically or [manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation). The default partition format for Ubuntu 18.04 is ext4. For new installations of Ubuntu 18.04 the Ubuntu installer will install Ubuntu by default in a single ext4 partition which contains a swap file instead of the old-fashioned swap partition.

Comment: If we do it by something else option, will it create a swap file or when we choose automatically??

Comment: For new installations of Ubuntu 18.04 you will automatically have a swap file if no swap partitions are present. You don't have to create it if either the *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* option or the *Something else* option is selected.

Comment: Thank you. I have around 50 times installed in some 12pcs..went to something else option and wasted 2xRAM space by creating swap partition. Here onwards I will not in 18.04.1.

Comment: Especially if you are installing Ubuntu on an SSD where disk space is at a premium.

Comment: Oh.. That's nice. All are ssds and M.2. I Will try to extend the space of swap partition to adjacent partitions.